# May be Lock one record(row) in database (MySql)?

Tags: mysql, sql

i have some records in my database and i want to lock them from delete action!
does exist any way to lock them?
i need Query for SQL (My Sql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two methods:

1. Add a `delete` trigger on the table to prevent certain rows from being deleted.
2. Maintain a separate table of "do not delete" records and define a foreign key constraint to the records you want to keep.